# Backslash in java

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with strings saved in a database, like this for example: `"311\315_316\336_337"`.  They have only one backslash and this is a problem in java. When I try to `s.replaceAll("\", "\\")` it doesn't work because the java compiler reads  the string `"311\315_316\336_337"` as `"311Í_316Þ_337"`.

I also try encoding and decoding the result of encoding `"311%C3%8D_316%C3%9E_337"` but the result of decoding is still `"311Í_316Þ_337"`?

How can I solve problem of one backslash?

I want to pass this string to function to do a process which splits numbers and the backslash is the delimiter, but this problem prevents me from doing that.

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\", "\");` should not even compile... Read the section about "Escape Sequences" here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: What makes you think you need to do anything with this data? Your program is not a Java compiler, and only the Java compiler needs double backslashes. Or a regular expression, but you wouldn't be using data from a database as a regular expression surely?

Answer (score 3):

The data in the database is OK, and you don't have to replace anything. String *literals*, written directly in the Java code, must have their backslash escaped by another backslash:

```
String s = "311\\315_316\\336_337";
System.out.println(s); // prints 311\315_316\336_337
```

But if you get those values from the database, you don't have anything to do:

```
String s = resultSet.getString(1);
System.out.println(s); // should print 311\315_316\336_337
```

Comment: problem not at System.out.println(s); but when i pass the string to function depend on backslash and use it as delimiter but all backslash disappear and string will be "311Í_316Þ_337"

Comment: Then the function is buggy, or doesn't do what you think is does. Without knowing what it does and how is does it, it's impossible to tell what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

In java strings, the backslash character is a control character. If you wish to include a literal backslash in a string, you must escape it with another backslash. e.g. `"\\"`

Comment: OK , how can i solve it ? all strings at database have only one backslash ??? 291_293\309

291_293\335_336
295\335_336
118_120\139_140

Comment: @user1571714 Don't try to change the values in the database. The only time you need to escape characters is in hard coded strings in java code. If the strings are loaded from the database, they don't need to be modified. Leave them as is.

Comment: i don't mean to change data at database but i ask about a solution in java ?? how to solve it in code ??

Comment: @user1571714: To split a java string on _one_ literal backslash, just do this: `String[] parts = s.split("\\");`.

Comment: backslash was disappear the string "311\315_316\336_337"  will be 311Í_316Þ_337 ,  String[] parts = s.split("\\"); this make application crash because the are no backslash in string :(((((

Answer (score 2):

in java, backslash `\` has a special meaning. in order to remove it, escape it with another backslash `\\`

try this:

```
s.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: backslash was disappear the string "311\315_316\336_337" will be 311Í_316Þ_337 , s.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\"); this make application crash because the are no backslash in string :(((((

Comment: You must double the blackslash twice (because of regular expression) : It gives : s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Unicode  \ = \u005c

Example:  "Folder\u005cSubfolder1\u005cSubfolder2"

Would result in the string "Folder\Subfolder1\Subfolder2"

You can see the full table here: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0020-007F

Comment: Why would you downgrade this.  I use unicode all the time and it works great.  At least explain why.

Comment: Sorry for not commenting the downvote -- was in a rush. IMO this is a useful comment, but not an answer. Hence, the downvote. Perhaps it wasn't proper of me to downvote something that is relevant -- my apologies.

Comment: Thanks for explaining 01es.  Thanks for Vote Baz.